# Thread locking not behaving properly when using appSettings to track whether complete

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, locking

I have a scenario where I need to override some application settings when an ASP.Net site spins up (and never again until the application pool resets.)

Here is the rough implementation:

```
        private object _lockObject = new object();

        private void OverrideSettings()
        {
            if (!ConfigurationUtility.GetAppSettingsValue<bool>(SETUPCOMPLETEAPPSETTINGKEY))
            {
                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    if (!ConfigurationUtility.GetAppSettingsValue<bool>(SETUPCOMPLETEAPPSETTINGKEY))
                    {
                        // snip...
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(SETUPCOMPLETEAPPSETTINGKEY, bool.TrueString);    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Usually, this works fine, but occasionally (when under load and the application pool resets,) I receive the following:

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: ArgumentException 
>       Exception message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'OverrideOfAppSettingsComplete'  Key being added:
>   'OverrideOfAppSettingsComplete'    at
>   System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean
>   add)    at
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseAdd(String
>   name, Object value)    at
>   Modules.LoadOverriddenSiteSettingsModule`1.OverrideSettings()
>   in c:\Modules\LoadOverriddenSiteSettingsModule.cs:line
>   203

This implies that either two threads entered the lock at the same time or that setting the "completed" application setting didn't take effect.

Does anyone have any insight, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your lock object static:

```
private static object _lockObject = new object();
```

Because you probably create several instances of this class that are accessed through the different threads, they all have their own lock object.

This means the can't 'see' each others locks.

Comment: That would certainly explain it. Thank you!